# How to update field in mongo db if not exist, If exists then update other fields

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

In My scenerio, User can give inputs in combinations as shown below:

```
1. id , status   -- This will simply check id and will update the status
2. id , externalId, status -- 
     i. Here If externalId is not present then will add externalId and also update the status
     ii. If externalId is present then will check both id & externalId and will update status
3. externalId, status -- Here will simpley check the externalId and will update the status.
```

Can we perform this all operation in one query?

Example is as follows:

In DB first time I will have document like this

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "status": "A",
}
```

1. If user inputs `id = 1` and `status = B` then need to add only one criteria of `id`. and change status to B. And db will save the document as below.

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "status": "B",
}
```

2. If user inputs both `id = 1` and `exteralId = 'xyz'` and `status = C` then document will look like this

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "externalId": "xyz",
  "status": "C",
}
```

3. If user inputs `exteralId = 'xyz'` and `status = D` then document will look like this

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "externalId": "xyz",
  "status": "D",
}
```

4.If user inputs both `id = 1` and `exteralId = 'xyz'` and `status = E` then document will look like this

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "externalId": "xyz",
  "status": "E",
}
```

5.But If user inputs both `id = 1` and `exteralId = 'pqr'` and `status = F` then document should not update externalId to `pqr` and also not change the status to `F`

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "externalId": "xyz",
  "status": "E",
}
This is previous document , because it is not updated
```

I can do this using java code. But fails to do this in only query.

```
        Query query = new Query();
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(id)) {
            criteria.and("_id").is(id);
        }
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(externalId)) {
            criteria.and("externalId").is(externalId);
        }
        query.addCriteria(criteria);
```

But when this query is failing when both ids are given in input. My requirement is if both ids are given then it should update in db if externalId is not exists.

Comment: I think its not good idea to do all conditions in a single update query, you can just do, select query of input `id` and then check all conditions in your code make update queries as per conditions.

Comment: Ok. Thank-you @turivishal. I was thinking get and update will take more time as compared to only update. But if this is not good then I will use get, apply conditions and then update .

Comment: Hi @turivishal Can you please help for question in link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65914720/how-to-group-data-using-mongo-template