# How to group data using mongo-template

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, match

I have to filter data based on a criteria and set a field `isObtained` true or false. Then I am trying to group the data based on field `grade`. This is my data:

```
{
  "school": "xyz",
  "studentName": "John Doe",
  "grade": "first",
  "Hobbies": [
    "Painting",
    "Singing"
  ],
  "language": [
    "English"
  ],
"sport": "Badminton",
  "totalStudyHours": 85
},
{
  "school": xyz,
  "studentName": "Jane Doe",
  "grade": "third",
  "Hobbies": [
    "Painting",
    
  ],
  "language": [
    "Spanish"
  ],
"sport": "Karate",
  "totalStudyHours": 65
},
{
  "school": "xyz",
  "studentName": "joey",
  "grade": "first",
  "Hobbies": [
    "Singing"
  ],
  "language": [
    "English",
    "Italian"
  ],
"sport": "Cricket",
  "totalStudyHours": 75,
  "ispassed": true,
  
},
{
  "studentName": "jason",
  "grade": "third",
  "Hobbies": [
    "Painting",
    
  ],
  "language": [
    "English",
    "Spanish"
  ],
  "sport": "Tennis",
  "totalStudyHours": 95,
  "isObtained": true
},
{
  "studentName": "mike",
  "grade": "third",
  "Hobbies": [
    "Singing"
  ],
  "language": [
    "English",
    "Italian"
  ],
  "sport": "Badminton",
  "totalStudyHours": 70,
  "isObtained": true
}
```

The expected output is

```
[
  {
    "grade": "first",
    "values": [
      {
        "studentName": "John Doe",
        "grade": "first",
        "Hobbies": [
          "Painting",
          "Singing"
        ],
        "language": [
          "English"
        ],
        "sport": "Badminton",
        "totalStudyHours": 85,
        "isObtained": true
      },
      {
        "studentName": "joey",
        "grade": "first",
        "Hobbies": [
          "Singing"
        ],
        "language": [
          "English",
          "Italian"
        ],
        "sport": "Cricket",
        "totalStudyHours": 75,
        "isObtained": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "grade": "third",
    "values": [
      {
        "studentName": "jason",
        "grade": "third",
        "Hobbies": [
          "Painting",
          
        ],
        "language": [
          "English",
          "Spanish"
        ],
        "sport": "Tennis",
        "totalStudyHours": 95,
        "isObtained": true
      },
      {
        "studentName": "mike",
        "grade": "third",
        "Hobbies": [
          "Singing"
        ],
        "language": [
          "English",
          "Italian"
        ],
        "sport": "Badminton",
        "totalStudyHours": 70,
        "isObtained": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In the mongoDb query, the `isObtained` field is set based on what field we want. For example, if we want records with sport as "Badminton" then the `isObtained` field will be true when sport is Badminton and false otherwise.

Here is the query, but I am facing problem in grouping based on `grade`.

```
db.students.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "school": "xyz"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sport": 1,
      "language": 1,
      "hobbies": 1,
      "isObtained": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$sport",
              "Badminton"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$match` your conditions
- `$group` by grade and make array of root documents in `values`,
- define required fields and check condition created field `isObtained` if `sport` is `Badminton` then true otherwise false

```
db.students.aggregate([
  { $match: { school: "xyz" } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$grade",
      values: {
        $push: {
          sport: "$sport",
          language: "$language",
          Hobbies: "$Hobbies",
          isObtained: {
            $cond: [{ $eq: ["$sport", "Badminton"] }, true, false]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3zYv2pBG69D)

---

If you want to go with dynamic approach then try `$mergeObjects` with `$$ROOT`,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V4JTMRp3M9b)

Comment: How can I limit the results while using $group? `db.students.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "school": "xyz"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "sport": 1,
      "isObtained": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$sport",
              "Badminton"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$grade",
      "values": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      },
      "name": {
        "$addToSet": "$grade"
      }
    }
  }
])`

Comment: You can't limit in group stage, you can do after that in $addFields/$project using $slice look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WEjCNuh55fy)

Comment: How can I use slice in mongo-template?

Comment: i am not sure, sorry i really don't know about mongo-template, what is the version of your mongodb?

Comment: Thankyou for all your help. The version is 4.4.0

Comment: okay $split should support as per your mongodb version, but make sure mongo-template documentation has implemented this function in latest mongo-template version.

Comment: If I want to add a field named studyHours after the  values array ,which has the sum of all totalStudyHours when isObtained is true.In other words for all records where isObtained is true ,their totalStudyHours we have to add and show in studyHours .How can i do that?

Comment: you can do something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/y9piIu9fC_s

Comment: Hii @turivishal It will be a great help if you could  please checkout this problem and share your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66167965/how-to-find-distinct-values-of-fields-using-facet-operation-in-mongodb